# Alternatives to HTML5 localStorage

Tags: html, local-storage

What are my alternatives to localStorage for persisting key/value pairs on the client?  Ideally I'm looking for something that the user can't inadvertently delete (as they theoretically could with localStorage).

Comment: I do not think it is possible to store information at the client side which cannot be deleted... That would provide all kinds of unwanted scenarios...

Comment: You don't own the client computers. This functionallity would be malware.

Comment: It's not HTML5 or standard, but the majority of browsers support an IE5+ feature called "userData persistance". Very few users know how to delete it. There are also "Flash cookies." Using these things in combination can be very difficult to defeat. Search online for the "everCookie"

Answer (score 22, accepted):

With HTML5 your local storage options are limited to the following:

- localStorage
- cookies
- Web SQL (in WebKit and Opera)
- IndexedDB (in all modern decent browsers)

… however, users can delete data in any of these stores, and that is as it should be.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative could also be localForage, a js library that provides the ease of use of localStorage with all the advanced features of IndexedDB.

One of the benefits: you don’t have to convert your data structures to JSON in order to save them in the datastore.

Its API has support for ECMAScript 6 Promises, which provide a better way of handling asynchronous code. 
Unfortunately it doesn’t work well with any IE under 11.

Comment: How does using a library to store data in localStorage mitigate the risk of the user deleting the contents of localStorage that the question is focused on?