# Alternative to localstorage for galery in new window

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I'm using localstorage to safe all image sources and open a gallery in a new tab.
This works just fine when cookie settings are turned the right way. But when they're blocking all stuff localstorage just won't work and the galery is empty. My current approach with localstorage:

Get sources:

```
var source = localStorage.getItem('source') /*current lightbox item*/ ,
  b_Link = localStorage.getItem('bl') /*backlink*/ ,
  srcsStr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("srcs")) /*all image sources as string*/ ,
  current = 0;
var image_o = [];

// Set current image and back link
document.getElementById("ig").src = source;
document.getElementById("back").href = b_Link;

// Set background by blurring the current image
document.getElementById("lightbox").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + source + "')";


// Set image sources object and set current counter of image
for (var i = 0; i < srcsStr.length; i++) {
  image_o.push({
    count: i,
    a_i: srcsStr[i]
  });

  if (source == image_o[i].a_i) {
    current = image_o[i].count;
  }
}
```

Read sources:

```
// Image gallery
let im = document.getElementsByClassName("p");

for (var i = 0; i < im.length; i++) {
  im[i].addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    var srcs = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < im.length; i++) {
      srcs[i] = im[i].src;
    }

    localStorage.setItem("srcs", JSON.stringify(srcs));

    localStorage.setItem("source", event.target.src);
    localStorage.setItem("bl", window.location);

    console.log(localStorage.getItem('source'));
    console.log(localStorage.getItem('bl'));

    window.location = "http://www.foxmoments.de/lightbox.html";
    // document.getElementById("innerlb").style.backgroundImage = "url('" + event.target.src + "')";
  }, false);
}
```

Comment: One posibilty could be to do an ajx call to some server side script and get the image data from there

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Alternatives to HTML5 localStorage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6909957/alternatives-to-html5-localstorage)

Comment: When you change to a new tab, are you in the same protocol and domain url ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I access right now your link 'http://www.foxmoments.de/lightbox.html' and I see your web server do a redirect from any request to https protocol. This could be the reason

localStorage scope is the same for same protocol and same domain.

Try to change the line

`window.location = "http://www.foxmoments.de/lightbox.html";`

To a url using same domain and same protocol